# how to merge 2 controller (6 Bays each) in HP DL370 G6

Tags: raid, hp, hard-drive

I am having a server DL370 G6 as seen in the image below, and I want to install Windows Server 2008 E. we are using it for camera recording. Each slot has 6 2 TB hard disks.

I want to merge both as Raid 1 for C drive and raid 5 for D where D drive should be 20 TB

I am not able to configure more than one slot 12 TB so my question is who to configure by adding 2 physical as one virtual

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In order to do this, you will need the [HP SAS expander card](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/arraycontrollers/sas-expander/index.html). These are available cheaply used or on eBay. This will allow you to use one RAID controller (the onboard Smart Array P410i) to accommodate up to 3 drive cages inside the server, plus an external SAS tape drive.

[image]

I use one in a DL370 G6 as described here: [Do SAS expanders work transparently with SAS controllers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/506583/do-sas-expanders-work-transparently-with-sas-controllers/506620#506620)